# ver 5.2.2:MIDIFileEditAndSync (Monterey), fails due do MIDINode(which was supposedly was renamed from AKMIDINode), is nowhere to be found

Tags: swift, audiokit

ver 5.2.2:Trying to incorporate MIDIFileEditAndSync (Monterey), MIDINode(which was supposedly was renamed from AKMIDINode), is nowhere to be found.

import AudioKit

import Foundation

import DunneAudioKit

class SequencerManager: ObservableObject {

var node: MIDINode!

}

Generates error Cannot find type 'MIDINode' in scope

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It fails the declaration. The rest of MIDIFileEditAndSync compiles and starts, but the MIDINote is not in 5.2.2 main branch

Comment: I don't think this is a good question for StackOverflow. You're right that the AudioKit documentation says MIDINode exists, but I think that just means the docs need updating. The repo for MIDIFileEditAndSync has an issues tab that I think would be a perfect place to post this info.